# JNDI Configuaration with Sql Server

Tags: jndi

This is my context.xml file.

```
<Context>
 <Resource name="jdbc/sqlserv"
   auth="Container"
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
   driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   maxActive="50"
   maxIdle="10"
   maxWait="15000"
   username="neeraj"
   password="12345"
   url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49159;databaseName=SCH-ADM"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
   logAbandoned="true" />
```

But When i run my project its give me some error looks like :- 
"Checking data source definitions for missing JDBC drivers...
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Neeraj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StrutsWithHibernate\build\web
Cannot deploy the module. The context.xml file seems to be broken. Check whether it is well-formed and valid."

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look like a valid context.xml file (note the missing `</Context>` tag at the end).